# How to make more precise a CNC?

Tags: raspberry-pi, stepper-motor, c++

I have a problem with precision for my CNC machine, when I try to draw a diagonal line on paper.

I use 3 unipolar stepper motors (RS 440-442) for 3 axis (x,y,z.) These 3 motors are controlled separately with 3 H-bridges (LN298N.) I use a PC power supply for them.

To control these 3 motors, I use a Raspberry Pi 2 and a C++ program. Here is the code https://bitbucket.org/crish4cks/steppermotor/src/master/src/StepperMotor.cpp

The problem: I want to improve the precision of the draw and I don't know if the problem is a sequential software problem like for example:

```
x.run(RIGHT, 1);   // turn the motor to 1 step in RIGHT side
y.run(RIGHT, 1);   // turn the Y motor to 1 step in RIGHT side
```

Should I use parallel programming? I also don't know how to change the value `stepAngle` for my 3 RS 440-442. (I changed 2D array of sequence don't worry.)

Documentation of the RS 440-442 ([ttps://docs.rs-online.com/e325/0900766b81579a91.pdf](http://ttps://docs.rs-online.com/e325/0900766b81579a91.pdf))

I'm not a Electrical Engineering student but a Computer Science student, and I do not have a good
understanding of stepper motors. Can you help me?

[image: the draw of the CNC of a diagonal line]

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include "StepperMotor.hpp"

using namespace std;

// Switching sequence for the 28BYJ48 (clockwise)
static const unsigned SEQUENCE[8][4] = { {1, 0, 0, 0},
                                         {1, 1, 0, 0},
                                         {0, 1, 0, 0},
                                         {0, 1, 1, 0},
                                         {0, 0, 1, 0},
                                         {0, 0, 1, 1},
                                         {0, 0, 0, 1},
                                         {1, 0, 0, 1} };

// stepAngle = (Step angle / gear reduction ratio) = (5.625 / 63.68395)
static const float stepAngle = 0.0883268076179f;

// Default constructor
StepperMotor::StepperMotor() {
    running = false;
    threshold = 0;
    current_pos = 0;
    sequence.resize(8);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sequence.size(); i++)
        sequence.at(i).resize(4);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sequence.size(); i++)
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < sequence.at(i).size(); j++)
            sequence.at(i).at(j) = SEQUENCE[i][j];
}

// Returns the number of steps associated to a certain angle
unsigned StepperMotor::getSteps(unsigned angle) const {
    return (unsigned) roundf(angle / stepAngle);
}

// Sets the GPIO outputs needed by inputs of the stepper motor driver (ULN2003APG)
// For more details concerning the wiringPi GPIO table conversion refere here:
// http://wiringpi.com/pins/
void StepperMotor::setGPIOutputs(unsigned in1, unsigned in2, unsigned in3, unsigned in4) {
    this->in1 = in1;
    pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
    this->in2 = in2;
    pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
    this->in3 = in3;
    pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
    this->in4 = in4;
    pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
}

// Sets a maximum threshold angle for the motor rotation
void StepperMotor::setThreshold(unsigned threshold) {
    assert(threshold < 180);
    this->threshold = threshold;
}

// Runs the stepper motor.
// * direction: 1 to go clockwise, -1 to go counterclockwise
// * angle: can assume values from 0 to 360 degrees
// * speed: from 20% (minimum speed) to 100% (maximum speed)
void StepperMotor::run(int direction, unsigned angle, unsigned speed) {
    float td;
    unsigned nsteps, count, ndegrees;

    running = true;

    // Check the direction and angle values
    assert(direction == 1 || direction == -1);
    assert(angle <= 360);

    // Check the speed value (5 speed modes allowed, from 20% to 100%)
    switch(speed) {
        case(20): break;
        case(40): break;
        case(60): break;
        case(80): break;
        case(100): break;
        default: return;
    }

    // Delay between each step of the switching sequence (in microseconds)
    td = (5 * 100 / (float) speed) * 1000;

    // Set the right number of steps to do, taking in account of the threshold
    if(abs(current_pos + direction * angle) > threshold && threshold != 0)
        ndegrees = threshold - direction * current_pos;
    else ndegrees = angle;

    nsteps = getSteps(ndegrees);

    // To go counterclockwise we need to reverse the switching sequence
    if(direction == -1)
        reverse(sequence.begin(), sequence.end());

    count = 0;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < nsteps; i++) {
        if(count == 8)
            count = 0;

        if(sequence.at(count).at(0) == 1)
            digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
        else digitalWrite(in1, LOW);

        if(sequence.at(count).at(1) == 1)
            digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
        else digitalWrite(in2, LOW);

        if(sequence.at(count).at(2) == 1)
            digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
        else digitalWrite(in3, LOW);

        if(sequence.at(count).at(3) == 1)
            digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
        else digitalWrite(in4, LOW);

        count++;
        delayMicroseconds(td); // minimum delay 5ms (speed 100%), maximum delay 25ms (speed 20%)
    }

    // Cleanup (recommended in order to prevent stepper motor overheating)
    digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in4, LOW);

    // Reverse again in order to restore the original vector for the next operations
    if(direction == -1)
        reverse(sequence.begin(), sequence.end());

    // Update the state
    this->nsteps += nsteps;
    current_pos += direction * ndegrees;
    running = false;
}
```

Comment: Realistically a high level language under a multi-tasking OS isn't a suitable way to sequence steppers.  Look at how 3d printers do it, with an Arduino-derived G-code interpreter that is then drip-fed G-code just in advance of need from a PC or pi.  You'll probably also want better steppers and good chopping drivers.

Comment: Thanks for your reading and I do this project with what I have. ^^

Comment: that's not going to work very well...

Comment: I won't comment on your choice of hardware, but to get as smooth a line as possible with what you have you can use [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). The cheap gearbox unipolar steppers have a lot of vibration so mechanical damping and operating very slowly may help.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Any self respecting machine tool will use motors with encoders (DC, BLDC, or AC) instead of stepper motors.

Comment: @user110971 that's actually not really true.  Plenty of stepper + index smaller scale CNC's.  I agree it's an old idea, but it does get used a lot.  The problem here is the step size and or completely unsuited software platform.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Maybe some low grade ones, bit I haven’t seen a CNC from any of our major competitors with stepper motors manufactured this century. I’ve even seen a machine tool with a 0.02 m^3 working volume and it didn’t use stepper motors. What kind of repeatability would you get from a stepper motor anyway? They are open loop and overshoot.

Comment: Open loop and overshoot having nothing to do with each other.  All you've really done is declare yourself *ignorant* of the sort of systems that do what the asker wants to do, but do it well.  Are steppers suitable for a dedicated high feed CNC machining center?  No, of course not.  Are they commonly used for smaller things at the dividing line between engraving and milling?  Most definitely, even to this day.  The asker's problem isn't that they are using steppers, but that they are using the wrong steppers with the wrong drives and the wrong software architecture.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I arrived at Bresenham's algorithm independently in about 1977 - LONG LONG after he did. I didn't know it existed formally until a student friend asked with help with a problem around 2000. I subsequently emailed him and he replied. | When I mentioned this on PICLIst in 2010 Olin replied "Yeah, he's a nice guy.  I met him a few times at SIGGRAPH conferences back when I was a graphics guy."

Comment: @BilalBrarou The solution for all of your current problems starts with **microstepping**, as said in the [Jeroen3's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/527490/102626).

Comment: @user110971 The world is plenty of low grade (even middle grade), and DIY CNC's and 3D printers that get by - sort of - with cheap bipolar steppers. No doubts that this is not the best possible solution, but it indeed works.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I will upgrade my code and I will buy some A4988 chips. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to improve the precision of the draw and I don't know if the problem is a sequential software problem

I suspect you are currently limited by the absolute resolution of **one step** (1.8 degree).  Parallel programming can't fix this. It will however be required later on when you need to calculate a path in advanced from a defined source to follow at a given speed. You won't be able to to that sequentially like you've written it now. *(You'd get calculate-go-stop-calculate-go-stop... with code like this)*

However, that is not where you're at yet. Right now you need to investigate microstepping. With the right hardware you can multiply your 200 steps to get a higher accuracy and thus a smoother line. At the costs of torque.

You haven't thought about holding torque yet, since you do this:

```
// Cleanup (recommended in order to prevent stepper motor overheating)
digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
```

Which means you always round to one full 1.8 degree step. That's your first bottleneck now.

Microstepping example:
[image]

I don't know how feasable microstepping is with your current L298N driver, maybe someone else can comment about that.

Comment: Using L298N's I believe you'd have to generate your own microstepping which could be very difficult as it needs to be current-controlled. Look at Allegro A4988, Trinamic SilentStepStick TM2100, DRV8825 etc. they are doing all the hard work for you. L298N is rather outdated for good motor control.

Comment: The current setup with the L298's and PI trying to do step sequence desperately needs to be replaced anyway...  - The listed drivers, and just about any MCU would be a far better choice, but choosing something for which there already is a G-code interpreter (either generic or at least as an open source 3d printer firmware) would drastically simplify.